# HTML + JS: Clear File Input on button click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-input

I want to tell my backend, I deleted the assigned file it already loaded:

```
<input id="pic" name="pic" type="file" onclick="this.value=null;" onchange="uploadFile(this);">
<button id="pic-delete" type="button" onclick="removeFile(this);"><i someicon></i></button>
```

where the onclick function looks like:

```
removeFile = function() {
    var ipt = document.getElementById("pic");
    ipt.value = null; // <--- problem here
    console.log("worked...")
}
```

my problem now is: I can differentiate the request in the browser Network tab whether I do nothing or hit the delete button. Both times the input field does not show up.
I wanted to add `ipt.value="DELETE"` so I can catch that in the backend, but this leads to an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

From what I can tell the error always occurs if I put anything else but `ipt.value = null` or `ipt.value = ""` in this line.

A fiddle with the full code to show the error: https://jsfiddle.net/rvc8sbjy/3/

Comment: the button doesn't contain the file. Your input does

Comment: I don't get any errors: https://jsfiddle.net/nhv1y7b6/

Comment: I fail to understand so far, why my fiddle produces an error, while yours does not. Would you have a look at mine please?

Comment: `inputFieldID` is an array with a string. Also you are splitting on `-` and not `___` which I think you are trying to?
Is there a reason you are complicating this?

Comment: yes the fields are dynamically created and `___` is the standard separator from the backend. I split because I add a `{inputfieldID}-delete` to every delete button for an input field and a `{inputfieldID}-label` for every label and so on ...

Comment: I simplified the fiddle to take your `string` <-> `array` point into the equation, but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors. The way you were trying to extract the ID is wrong. A much easier approach is to just use `.replace`

```
      var inputFieldID = v.id.replace("-delete", "");
```

Second - you can't set the value to an non-empty string. To reset it just set it to an empty one:

```
          ipt.value = "";
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5yqohjzv/

Comment: The last thing here makes perfectly sense! thanks! How would I "mark" the file to be deleted on backend? My problem is, I cannot differentiate between "delete" and "nothing was changed".

Comment: If you are making api-calls in the `uploadFile` function, just check `v.files.length` to see if there is none or has some.

Comment: I might need more code in your example to understand

Comment: in the browser console, I can not differentiate between "the user has not touched the file" -> it does not show up in the request and "the user has hit the delete button -> value is set to null" -> it does not show up in the request. I wished for something like `value = null` -> user did not touch it, continue. But if `value = "REMOVE"` the backend knows the file is to be deleted.

Comment: my workaround would be to place a hidden field there and save the names of the deleted fields in there and send it upon form sending ...?

Comment: I think I need more example code to follow this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240728/discussion-between-xtlc-and-salmin-skenderovic).